# How to update records in a ref map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given the following scenario:

```
(defrecord Person [firstname lastname])
(def some-map (ref {}))

(dosync
  (alter some-map conj {1 (Person. "john" "doe")})
  (alter some-map conj {2 (Person. "jane" "jameson")}))
```

To change the firstname of "joe" to "nick", I do the following:

```
(dosync
  (alter some-map (fn [m]                   
                  (assoc m 1 
                       (assoc (m 1) :firstname "nick")))))
```

What is the idiomatic way of doing this in Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use update-in, for this case, assoc-in is exactly what you want.

`(dosync (alter some-map assoc-in [1 :firstname] "nick"))`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: For your example `assoc-in` is better, since you ignore the previous value. Keeping this answer for cases where you actually need the previous value:

The `update-in` is there to update nested structures:

```
(alter some-map update-in [1 :firstname] (constantly "nick"))
```

The last argument is a function on the value to be "replaced" (like `assoc`, it does not replace but returns a new structure.) In this case the old value is ignored, hence the `constantly` function that always returns "nick".

Comment: you can leave out the anonymous function wrapper: `(alter some-map update-in  [1 :firstname] (constantly "nick"))`

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat Thanks, I keep forgetting about the optional arguments to higher order functions in Clojure, will edit.

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but thank you for your suggestion. I did not know about constantly; now I understand why my other attempts failed.